# How to filter object based on conditional argument?

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function with two arguments,

**Arg 1:** Object `{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}`

**Arg 2:** Condition `((prop, key) => prop >= 3))`

Here based on the condition we need to filter the object and provide the result as array of objects.

The code that I have tried,

```js
const pickBy = (a, b) => {
  const data = Object.values(a).filter(b);
  console.log(data)
}

pickBy({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, ((prop, key) => prop >= 3))
```

**Current Result:** `[3,4]`

**Expected Result:** `[{c:3}, {d:4}]`

Comment: you are filtering the keys of the object a. No key matches your filter function

Comment: @NumanIjaz, Sorry edited now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the entries, filter by handing over the right format for filtering function and build objects of filtered entries.

```js
const
    pickBy = (object, filterFn) => Object
        .entries(object)
        .filter(([k, v]) => filterFn(v, k))
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));

console.log(pickBy({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, (prop, key) => prop >= 3));
```